# Add separator in grouped tableview cell

Tags: iphone, tableview

I have table cell with 1 textfield & 1 uiswitch placed in single cell. I have table cell of height 100. How can I add separator to this cell so that there is distinction between textfield & uiswitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are adding subviews to your cell, you would need to create a custom view with a switch and a separator (a graphic or something else) to add to your cell as a subview.

Question: if you are adding a switch and a textfield, shouldn't they be in two separate cells anyway? That way you would get a natural horizontal divider.

Comment: [customizing cells guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) It is really useful every now and then.